# How to convert the id to refs for unique ids in React/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

Tried to replace the id to refs element.

Below code working fine in refs

```
    document.getElementById('search').style.display = 'none';

to 
       (this.refs.search as HTMLFormElement).style.display = 'none';
```

when unique element using in id ,how to use refs.

This is working code . How to convert  document.getElementById to refs

```
showLessDetail(index: any) {  
    if (document.getElementById('divLoan' + index)) {
      document.getElementById('divLoan' + index).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

html code

```
<div className="divLoan"    ref={'divLoan' + this.props.index}    id={'divLoan' + this.props.index}    >
        ----
        ---
   </div>
```

Comment: Where are you creating the ref, and what component are you attaching the ref to? You haven't posted any of that code. Also, you don't need to use refs to set style. You can just use the style prop. Refs are useful for things like `getBoundingClientRect` etc...

Comment: Really it not an "Angular way".The Angular way to make a display.none is using [style.display], e.g. , you can use `[style.display]="condition?'none':null`. BTW you can  use ViewChildren or ViewChild to get the html ref of an element, see the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild